# "QGIS: Displaying labels outside polygons for line features inside using field values"

Tags: line, geospatial, polygon, qgis, labeling

How can I display labels for line features in a QGIS line layer, where the label should appear outside a polygon if the line feature is inside the polygon, and otherwise appear as it is? I have activated the "name" field for labeling the line features.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXCUh.png)

difference (
$geometry,
buffer (
aggregate(
'polygon',
'collect',
buffer ($geometry,15)
),
0
))
i tried the above expression but not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
with_variable('polyGeom',overlay_intersects(layer:='Polygon',expression:=@geometry)[0],
with_variable('centroid',centroid(@geometry),
with_variable('offsetY',100,
make_point(x_max(@centroid),y_max(@polyGeom)+@offsetY)
)))
```

[image]